# Is PubSubHubbub automatically supported for every Feedburner feed

Tags: feedburner, websub

I [read here](http://smarterware.org/2746/how-to-pubsubhubbub-enable-your-sites-feed) it's an option which must be turned on, but maybe it's changed since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope someone from Google comes here and respond to this, but I believe all feeds have the "discovery" part in them, which means they all point to the google hosted hub, however, the realtime approach only works if the publisher pings the hub as well when its feed(s) have been updated, and this can be done with Pingshot.

This is the behavior we have seen at [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com) for these feeds.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on some PuSH things recently, and since FeedBurner is still one of the main players out there it's worth noting that at least as of today, what I'm seeing is that any feed, regardless of the Pingshot setting, will publish the `rel=self` and `rel=hub` link tags, and a subscriber can subscribe to the topic using that information, and will receive webhooks on the callback when content changes. Basically, *yes* PuSH **is supported for all Feedburner feeds**. I have not yet found a Feedburner feed that doesn't publish content changes through the hub if there's an active subscription.

It is true that *realtime* PuSH is only going to happen if something pings Feedburner when new content is available in the source feed, but the documentation that I've seen if very unclear about the behavior in general. It actually makes it seem like PuSH is tied to Pingshot, which, as I just said, doesn't seem to be the case.

A couple additional bits of information:

- The leases I'm getting for the feeds I've tested with are 5 days
- Even if/when feeds are coming served over HTTPS ([example](https://feeds.feedburner.com/freakonomicsradio)), the `rel=self` address is **not** HTTPS, so the PuSH topic is potentially different than the feed address you may have captured or be using for polling purposes.
- There are some interesting and useful pages on the hub's web interface ([example](https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/topic-details?hub.url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.99percentinvisible.org%2F99percentinvisible)), though I'm not sure why some things that seem like the should have data do not, so use with caution.